# wcscoll returns different result than expected

Tags: c, widechar

Consider this code:

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "pl_PL.UTF-8");
    printf("%d\n", wcscoll(L"ą", L"b"));
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
158
```

But I'd expect it to be `-1`, since ą is just before b in the polish alphabet. Why did it return 158? And if not in this way, how can one compare words alphabetically?

Comment: Is the polish locale actually installed on your machine? Does the `sort` utility sort correctly with that locale? First step in debugging this sort of thing is always to check standard library return values, in this case `if(setlocale(...) = NULL)...`

Comment: @rici no it doesn't, actually. So I guess it's OS-dependant?

Comment: No, it's a question of which locales you have installed on the machine. So its more configuration-dependent than OS, but I guess it depends on what you mean by OS-dependent.

Comment: @rici Well, it is OS-dependent also because the only locale name defined by the language is `"C"`. Any other locale is OS dependent.

Comment: @rodrigo: technically true, but the solution in this case is probably not "change your OS" or even "verify that your OS supports more than one locale". (I upvoted your answer without quibbling the latter check :) )

Comment: @rici: What I meant is that maybe OP copied the `pl-PL.UTF-8` name from a Linux example and they are using Windows or some other OS, as Kevin's answer suggests.

Answer (score 2):

I tried it in my Linux machine and I get `1` as output, positive just like yours.

Then I edited the supported locales at `/etc/locale.gen`, uncommented `pl_PL.UTF-8` (not enabled by default), run `sudo locale-gen` and now it gives `-4`, that is negative, as expected.

The conclusion is that your system configuration, as is, does not support the selected locale.

Answer (score 1):

Check the return value of `setlocale`; it's probably not recognizing your country/codepage string.

[MS locale names use dashes, not underscores](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf.aspx). If you're on Windows, try passing `pl-PL` instead of `pl_PL.UTF-8`.